# How to make wordpress get_field() faster

Tags: wordpress, performance

I have 80 post entries which have a custom field with number value. When I get them with query_posts( $args ), and then in foreach get that property "get_field('date_last_check')" it take insane 15 seconds.

If I try to solve it with meta_query

```
            array(
                'key'=>'date_last_check',
                'compare' => '<',
                'value' => time() - (24 * 60 * 60)
            )
```

It also takes 12 seconds to complete that query.

Is there anything i can do to solve this slowness ?

Comment: Where is the time being spent? On getting those 80 posts from the Database, getting the single meta value from the individual posts or something else entirely? Generally, that doesn't sound like it should take any significant amount of time.

Comment: Time is spent in getting 80x get_field('date_last_check'), or in single query where is needed 'relation' => 'OR, since wordpres do not fill records in wp_postmeta till you do not save every single post in administration manually again (so if you do not use Or on Not Exist, it will not show all posts in query results in case you for example want order by that field)

Comment: 80 simple select statements shouldn't take that long. Have you measured that the time is spent there or are you guessing? have you looked at the SQL that is generated by your query with $query->request? How big is your installation in general, and how complex is your query?

Comment: I remove get_field call in each result is -20s.

I add :
MetaKey1 != "" AND ((MetaKey2 Not Exist) or (metaKey2 Exist AND (metaKey2 < 1000))
And query time has +20 s.

Just googled that this behavior of wordpress meta keys is "Expected", and is slow by design, and that i should not use them for any posts filtering and just for cases where you have single post and want its data.

Comment: Well that did not helped my much but i found 2 alternatives -

1. In phpmyadmin index 'value' column in 'wp_postmeta' table
2. Set meta key data (in my case 'metaKey2') to all posts (i did query selected all with Not Exist, and called  update_post_meta() for it. So now i did not needed part with '(MetaKey2 Not Exist) or ' and now its working at bearable speed.

Am just quite dissapointed in wp with this, table has 22k records but wueried records with that post_type were only 80, and it needed 30s, oh god.

Comment: I'm surprised by your results. I'm working on large installations as well, and have never run into this problem. I'd get the SQL, see why it is so slow with EXPLAIN and then try to change the query to get more effective SQL.

Comment: Here is nice example , i was also inspied with solution from here - http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Expensive-meta-query-Is-there-a-better-way-td38467.html